# jQuery-ui-tooltip arrow position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, tooltip

I'm using jquery-ui-tooltip. And I want the tooltip arrow (connector/triange) to change its position according to where the tooltip appears. Now it's fixed to left bottom, that causes issue like on pic below.
[image]
The site is here: http://g1un.ru/navystavke/ 
Maybe somebody can offer a better plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `position` of UI tooltip according to your need.

```
Default: { my: "left top+15", at: "left bottom", collision: "flipfit" }
```

Ex:

```
$( ".selector" ).tooltip({
  position: { my: "left+15 center", at: "right center" }
});
```

I think this can help you. [Reference](https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position)

Comment: I did it already. It fits the most of tooltips, but not the ones, which are too close to the right border of the document. Also it doesn't help when the tooltip appears below the link. Of course, I can create special option for every tooltip, but i am looking for more optimal automatic dicision.